I am in need of recommendations for ROS2 libraries or frameworks for 3D navigation
I am a computer science student participating in a robotics project. Due to budget constraints, we are using a 2D LIDAR as a 3D LIDAR by rotating it. So far, I have managed to make the robot navigate with the LIDAR in its normal 2D mode, but now I need to make the leap from 2D to 3D navigation. I have been researching ROS2 tools to make this possible but haven't had much success. The one that showed the most potential was rtabmap_ros, but it is primarily designed for depth cameras, and I couldn't adapt it to my LIDAR. Additionally, it was developed for ROS1, and not everything has been transferred to ROS2 yet. I would like suggestions for tools that can work with my LIDAR for both mapping and 3D navigation.

I recommend you to take a look at:
voxel layer
https://github.com/SteveMacenski/spatio_temporal_voxel_layer/
https://octomap.github.io/
https://github.com/ANYbotics/grid_map/
https://github.com/ANYbotics/elevation_mapping/

If you are navigating on planar, or close to planar terrain nav2 with stvl as mentioned above makes sense.
If you can find planar areas, octomap got a way to remove the floor and you can project the map to get the planar area where you can navigate again with nav2. Or (vox_nav, mesh navigation) and also grid maps mentioned below. Other interesting work are FAR Planner which process raw point clouds in a sense.
It gets tricky if the terrain is full of areas hard to navigate since you will have to use elevation mapping based on grid maps or similar with Anymal type robot!
